# How to conditionally prevent branch collapsing?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am using Material tree, just like any tree in these examples - https://material.angular.io/cdk/tree/examples. The only difference is that my tree is dynamic - every node has controls to create or delete nodes

Is there a way to prevent branch from collapsing under certain circumastances? So that user could not click on it to collapse and thus always saw the branch expanded, for example if child nodes has some errors to be fixed by user. Sure if errors got fixed then user can collapse the branch

Answer (score 0):

I invite you to check the first example, [Tree with flat nodes](https://material.angular.io/cdk/tree/examples) of Tree | Angular Material,

you have a way to prevent a branch to collapse.

For example, you can change the first item of the example with:

```
  {
    name: 'Fruit',
    expandable: false,
    isExpanded: true,
    level: 0,
  },
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c4baw7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-tree-flat-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-tree-flat-example.html

[image: Example of a branch not able to collapse]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can prevent a branch from collapsing under certain circumstances by setting the treeControl property of your mat-tree element to an instance of the FlatTreeControl class and implementing the isExpandable and getChildren methods.

In the isExpandable method, you can check if a node has errors and return true if it does, and false otherwise. In the getChildren method, you can return the child nodes of the current node if it has errors, and an empty array otherwise.

Here's an example implementation:
`   import { FlatTreeControl } from '@angular/cdk/tree';

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-my-tree',
templateUrl: './my-tree.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./my-tree.component.css']
})
export class MyTreeComponent implements OnInit {

treeControl = new FlatTreeControl<any>(
    node => node.level, // level function
    node => node.expandable // isExpandable function
);

// ... other code

 isExpandable(node: any) {
    return node.errors && node.errors.length > 0;
 }

 getChildren(node: any) {
   return node.errors && node.errors.length > 0 ? node.children : [];
 }

 // ... other code

}
```

}`. In the above code, we have created a FlatTreeControl instance and set it as the treeControl property of our mat-tree. We have also implemented the isExpandable and getChildren methods to prevent branches from collapsing when a node has errors. The isExpandable method checks if the node has errors and returns true if it does. The getChildren method returns the child nodes of the current node if it has errors, and an empty array otherwise.

With this implementation, the user will not be able to collapse a branch if it has errors, and the branch will always be expanded until the errors are fixed.